# Natural logged dependent variable and the ratio problem with two-way fixed-effects panel model

Tags: regression, econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, log-linear

In a non-peer-reviewed (yet?) paper, [Bartlett and Partnoy (BP) (2020)](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3605606) discuss some under-appreciated issues related to using ratios as the dependent variable. Some but not all problems are dealt with when taking the natural log of the ratio (see pages 24-28). I want to make sure I'm understanding the ratio problem in OLS with $\ln(DV_{ratio})$ and get some insight on how the assumptions and solutions differ for my main model, two-way fixed effects (TWFE) model **(E1)**--bias-corrected as **(E4)** below:

$$
\ln(\frac{GDP_{it}}{population_{it}}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 treatment_{it} + \lambda_{t} + \alpha_i + \epsilon_{it} 
\tag{E1}
$$

BP show that **(E1)** without unit and time FE (i.e. as OLS) is equivalent to **(E2)** and must assume (often incorrectly) that there is a perfectly linear relationship between $\ln(GDP_{it})$ and $ln(population_{it})$ to be unbiased (i.e. the coefficient for $\ln(population_{it})$ must be exactly equal to $1$):

$$ 
\ln(GDP_{it}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 treatment_{it} + 1\ln(population_{it}) + \epsilon_{it}  
\tag{E2} 
$$

BP demonstrate that **(E3)** gives the unbiased model in OLS:

$$ 
\ln(\frac{GDP_{it}}{population_{it}}) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 treatment_{it} + \beta_2 \ln(population_{it}) + \epsilon_{it}  
\tag{E3} 
$$

Table 1 below demonstrates the differences among the correct and incorrect models described by BP, using data for a paper I'm writing. In **OLS 1**, I show that **log_pop** does not have a perfectly linear relationship with **log_gdp**, which is not a surprise in this context. Thus, my understanding is that **OLS 5** (or **OLS 4** not discussed by BP) is the correct way to obtain the unbiased effect of $treatment$ on **log_gdp_pc**. The more intuitive model **OLS 2** (equivilent to **OLS 3**) is biased.

#### Question 1:

Are **(E3)** above and **OLS 4 & 5** in Table 1 the correct ways to model this relationship in the OLS context with $\ln(DV_{ratio})$? I know that in the linear context, without taking the $\ln()$, controlling for $population$ on the RHS with only $GDP$ on the LHS is not the same as having $GDP/capita$ on the LHS. I want to be confident in explaining to readers/reviewers that the more intuitive **OLS 2** would actually cause bias in **treatment** in the context when values are $ln()$.

#### Table 1.

```
========================================================================
                                 Dependent variable:                    
             -----------------------------------------------------------
              log_gdp  log_gdp_pc (log_gdp-log_pop)  log_gdp  log_gdp_pc
               OLS 1     OLS 2          OLS 3         OLS 4     OLS 5   
------------------------------------------------------------------------
treatment               0.165**        0.165**       0.161**   0.161**  
                        (0.080)        (0.080)       (0.080)   (0.080)  
                                                                        
log_pop      0.918***                               0.919***  -0.081*** 
              (0.020)                                (0.020)   (0.020)  
                                                                        
Constant     10.365***  9.559***      9.559***      10.352*** 10.352*** 
              (0.199)   (0.018)        (0.018)       (0.199)   (0.199)  
                                                                        
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations   1,155     1,155          1,155         1,155     1,155   
R2             0.639     0.004          0.004         0.640     0.017   
========================================================================
```

Table 2 provides analogous models in the TWFE context, using the same data and the plm(model = "within") package. BP does not discuss TWFE specification, but I observe analogous patterns in Table 2 to those in Table 1. Based on this, it appears that the unbiased model is not **(E1)** but is the less intuitive **(E4)**:

$$
\ln(\frac{GDP_{it}}{population_{it}}) = \beta_1 treatment_{it} + \beta_2 \ln(population_{it}) + \lambda_{t} + \alpha_i + \epsilon_{it} 
\tag{E4}
$$

#### Question 2:

The main model for my current research is a TWFE model. I assumed that **(E1)** was the correct model before I came across BP. Is it, in fact, correct that **(E4)** and **TWFE 4 & 5** in Table 2 are the appropriate models to get unbiased effects of **treatment** on $\ln(GDP/capita)$?

(part 2) The coefficient in **TWFE 1** for **log_pop** is not close to $1$. This feels intuitive, since coefficients are for deviations from the unit mean and not raw values. Is there a similar condition in the TWFE context to $\beta = 1$ in the OLS context like in **(E2)**?

#### Table 2.

````
============================================================================
                                     Dependent variable:                    
                 -----------------------------------------------------------
                  log_gdp  log_gdp_pc (log_gdp-log_pop)  log_gdp  log_gdp_pc
                  TWFE 1     TWFE 2        TWFE 3        TWFE 4     TWFE 5  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
treatment                    -0.025        -0.025       0.059***   0.059*** 
                            (0.028)        (0.028)       (0.020)   (0.020)  
                                                                            
log_pop          -0.264***                              -0.281*** -1.281*** 
                  (0.041)                                (0.042)   (0.042)  
                                                                            
factor(year)2014 0.050***   0.040***      0.040***      0.050***   0.050*** 
                  (0.011)   (0.015)        (0.015)       (0.011)   (0.011)  
                                                                            
factor(year)2015 0.140***   0.120***      0.120***      0.141***   0.141*** 
                  (0.011)   (0.015)        (0.015)       (0.011)   (0.011)  
                                                                            
factor(year)2016 0.253***   0.224***      0.224***      0.248***   0.248*** 
                  (0.011)   (0.015)        (0.015)       (0.011)   (0.011)  
                                                                            
factor(year)2017 0.303***   0.278***      0.278***      0.298***   0.298*** 
                  (0.011)   (0.015)        (0.015)       (0.011)   (0.011)  
                                                                            
factor(year)2018 0.345***   0.306***      0.306***      0.341***   0.341*** 
                  (0.011)   (0.015)        (0.015)       (0.011)   (0.011)  
                                                                            
factor(year)2019 0.399***   0.351***      0.351***      0.394***   0.394*** 
                  (0.011)   (0.015)        (0.015)       (0.011)   (0.011)  
                                                                            
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations       1,155     1,155          1,155         1,155     1,155   
R2                 0.712     0.508          0.508         0.714     0.750   
============================================================================
```
````

Comment: I rewrote this as a [short version](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/634967/natural-log-of-ratios-and-two-way-fixed-effects-model-bias). If either of them ever gets an answer, I will close the other.