# Natural log of ratios and two-way fixed-effects model bias

Tags: regression, econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, lognormal-distribution

[Bartlett and Partnoy (BP) (2020)](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3605606) show that OLS with natural log dependent variables that are ratios must include the $\ln(denominator)$ on the RHS in order to avoid bias (see pages 24-28) unless one makes the assumption that  $\ln(denominator)$ would a slope of $1$ with $\ln(numerator)$ on the LHS. This is because a $\ln(ratio)$, e.g., $\ln(\frac{GDP_{it}}{population_{it}})$ is equivalent to $\ln(GDP_{it})-\ln(population_{it})$. Thus, any OLS model with $\ln(\frac{GDP_{it}}{population_{it}})$ on the LHS is implicitly assuming:
$$\ln(GDP_{i})= \beta_0 + X_i + 1\ln(population_{i}) + \epsilon_{i}
\tag{E1}$$

The solution is to include the $\ln(denominator)$ on the RHS, like in TWFE 5. They do not discuss these issues in the context of panel data with two-way fixed-effects (TWFE) like (E2).

#### Questions

Is there any reason to doubt BP in the OLS context? Are (E2) and model TWFE 5 below the correct model to identify the unbiased effect for *treatment* in the TWFE panel context? Is model TWFE 2 indeed giving a biased coefficient for *treatment*? Is there any methods literature discussing this issue of $\ln(ratio)$ in the OLS or TWFE context?

In model TWFE 5, $\beta_2$ is not close to $1$ but is $0.92$ in the [OLS version of the model without unit FE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/633748/natural-logged-dependent-variable-and-the-ratio-problem-with-two-way-fixed-effec). How can I understand BP's point about linearity between $\ln(\frac{numerator}{denominator})$ in the context of unit fixed-effects?

#### Equation for model TWFE 4 below that corrects bias from linearity assumption:

$$
\ln(\frac{GDP_{it}}{population_{it}}) = \beta_1 treatment_{it} + \beta_2 \ln(population_{it}) + \lambda_{t} + \alpha_i + \epsilon_{it} 
\tag{E2}
$$

#### Two-Way Fixed-Effects Models:

````
============================================================================
                                     Dependent variable:                    
                 -----------------------------------------------------------
                  log_gdp  log_gdp_pc (log_gdp-log_pop)  log_gdp  log_gdp_pc
                  TWFE 1     TWFE 2        TWFE 3        TWFE 4     TWFE 5  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
treatment                    -0.025        -0.025       0.059***   0.059*** 
                            (0.028)        (0.028)       (0.020)   (0.020)  
                                                                            
log_pop          -0.264***                              -0.281*** -1.281*** 
                  (0.041)                                (0.042)   (0.042)  
                                                                            
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
TWFE                YES       YES            YES           YES       YES
Observations       1,155     1,155          1,155         1,155     1,155   
R2                 0.712     0.508          0.508         0.714     0.750   
============================================================================
```
````

Comment: This is a short version of [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/633748/natural-logged-dependent-variable-and-the-ratio-problem-with-two-way-fixed-effec). I think the other version was too long. If either gets an answer, I will close the other as a duplicate.

Comment: Isn't this just another way of saying that if GDP per capita is correlated with population, you should control for population in your model? If so, this makes sense, assuming that population affects GDP and not the other way around.

Comment: @Eoin I think that's right. If so, there are likely many papers that unnecessarily suffer from OVB. Another way of looking at it might be to say that $\ln(GDP/capita)$ is an "inherent" measure of something independent of the relationship between $GDP$ and $population$. If that's so, would adjusting for $\beta_2\ln(population_{it})$ on the RHS be adding measurement error and bias to $\beta_1$? Certainly it's true that one gets distinct $\beta_1treatment$ with and without it when $\beta_2 \neq 1$. Is this philosophical or is one of these correct?

Answer (score 1):

A model like $$log(y/z) = f(x)$$ relates to a linear relationship like $$y = g(x) \cdot z$$ with $g(x) = e^{f(x)}$ where the model only determines the slope.

On a scatterplot of $y$ and $z$ this could look like the first image below where $y/z$ has different values depending in the value of $x$.

The second image below shows a relationship between $y$ and $z$ that is not linear but a powerlaw relationship like $y = g(x) z^{0.7}$.

In the second image the factor $g(x)$ is constant and independent from $x$. But if you would fit with a linear model, then you would observe an effect for $x$. I wouldn't say that such effect is bias, but the interpretation should be nuanced. It is only an effect in a statistical relationship. The parameter $x$ can be used to predict the ratio $y/z$. But, it doesn't necessarily mean that it is a true relationship and/or that $x$ needs to play some role in a causal relationship.

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks, I believe I caused some confusion by saying "perfectly linear" when I meant "slope of exactly 1" at the start (now edited). I want to give this bounty to someone. Can you take another swing by relating the answer more specifically to getting an unbiased $\beta_1$; elaborate on "It is only an effect in a statistical relationship"; and how TWFE matters here or not?

Comment: @dcoy the slope doesn't need to be exactly 1. In the logarithmic scale it does, but in the non-logarithmic scale it relates to linear relationships with the slope depending on the other parameters. Like you see in the first graph where I have drawn several different slopes and you see two different populations aligned along different slopes.

Comment: The linked paper explains the non-logarithmic assumptions in greater detail, and I think I understand those (probably not as well as you would, I'll admit). I'm trying to get the intuition for why models TWFE4 & TWFE5 have the same slope for $\beta_1$ and whether TWFE2 or TWFE5 gives the "better" (the problem is defining "better") or unbiased $\beta_1$ in the $\ln()$ context in OLS and how that changes in the TWFE context where coefficients are for deviations from the mean: $\ln(x)_{it} - \overline{\ln(x)}_i$  .